# How to use Vaadin as a Wildfly module

Tags: maven, deployment, vaadin, wildfly, jboss-modules

I noticed that the Vaadin JARs take up a sizeable percentage of my test application WAR file size, does anyone have any experiences on using vaadin dependencies as a wildfly module and just referencing it from the application?

I'm currently using vaadin 14.6.1 and wildfly 24.0.1.

I tried to use vaadin with the scope provided in my maven project, but oddly I couldn't compile the frontend dependencies doing this, I was getting this error:

```
 Execution default of goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:14.6.1:build-frontend fa
iled: Unable to compute frontend dependencies: com.vaadin.flow.router.Route -> [Help 1]
```

What I expect at the end is to have a WAR file without the vaadin JARs, and then put those JARs somewhere where the wildfly could load them as dependencies of the WAR.

I would like to have some direction to the right path and know if there's any working solution to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the reason you want to do that? The risk is that you will update your Vaadin version in the app but forget to update it in the Wildfly server.

Comment: That's a good point @SimonMartinelli , the reason I want to do it is because I have many vaadin applications sharing the same libs and I want to centralize them.

Comment: What is the benefit you get from this centralization?